# Crontab Source Command

Tags: python, bash, shell, cron

I'm trying add job to cron , ım having this issue :

```
You must source this script: $ source /home/flask/bin/activate
```

And when I try to use `.` in its place ````source```

Then this is the problem :

```
mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
.: .: is a directory
```

Here is my crontab file :

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PYTHONPATH="/home/flask/"
* * * * * bash -l  /home/flask/bin/activate && python3 application/script/myscript.py
```

Any help would be great , many thanks.

Comment: You didn't show the offending part of the `activate` scripts, which produces the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have this in your crontab

```
bash -l foo && bar
```

cron (or, more strictly speaking, the shell invoked by cron) is first going to run `bash -l foo` and then, as a separate command, `bar`. This probably not what you want. (It will make any changes to the shell environment done by `foo` local to that instance of bash, and thus invisible to `bar`). Also, *foo* is supposed to be a filename, so `.` won't work there (hence the ". is a directory" message).

It might work to do

```
bash -c ". /whatever/activate; python3 foo.py"
```

but I would recommend to put all the stuff required in a single shell script, and invoke that script from cron.

I'm not sure about the tty stuff. It looks like something *really* wants a terminal to talk to, but that might be your bash_profile or something similar, since you're running bash with `-l`.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it with this :

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PYTHONPATH="/home/flask/"
* * * * * bash -c ". /home/flask/bin/activate; python3 application/script/myscript.py"
```

Thansk to Ture Pålsson's answer

Comment: You should not need the `bash -c` wrapper with that `SHELL=/bin/bash`